# Zend Framework setHttpResponseCode is not modifying the response header

Tags: zend-framework, header

I'm using zend framework ErrorController, but for some reason when an application error occurs, setHttpResponseCode should set it to 500, but when I

> echo get_headers("my_url")

, I am still getting

> Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200)

Any idea how to modify the header to header ('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
event when I write this line just before get_headers() I still got the same 200 headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call sendHeaders() after settHttpResponseCode().

This is from the doc block in ZF:

```
/**
 * Send all headers
 *
 * Sends any headers specified. If an {@link setHttpResponseCode() HTTP response code}
 * has been specified, it is sent with the first header.
 *
 * @return Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract
 */
public function sendHeaders()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I discovered the error, I'm implementing ACL in my project, so actually these headers displayed are for the login page, not the actuall requested url.